# How to remove sort by keyword from default sorting of product in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, css, woocommerce

Hi I am working on a woocommerce website and i want to remove the sort by keyord from default sorting of products,For example:sort by popularity,sort by price.I only want it to be Popularity and price.No sort by wording in front of it

Answer (score 3):

Here's the code that you need to add to your functions.php in your theme or child theme folder:

```
// Edit WooCommerce dropdown menu item of shop page//
// Options: menu_order, popularity, rating, date, price, price-desc

function my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby( $orderby ) {
    unset($orderby["price"]);
    return $orderby;
}
add_filter( "woocommerce_catalog_orderby", "my_woocommerce_catalog_orderby", 20 );
```

The "unset" you see in the above code specifies which options you want to be removed.
Here are the default options that woocommerce uses:

- **menu_order** = Default sorting
- **popularity** = Sort by popularity
- **rating** = Sort by average rating
- **date** = Sort by newness
- **price** = Sort by price: low to high
- **price-desc** = Sort by price: high to low

Hope that helps,
Cheers

Comment: I don't think you understood the question. He's trying to remove the "sort by" text prefix on each option.